# How can I associate two objects in main in Java

Tags: java, class, object

I'm trying to associate a cat object to a person object.

Person class:

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private String tcNo;
    private Cat cat;
    public Person (String name, String tcNo) {
        this.name = name;
        this.tcNo = tcNo;
    }
    public String getName() { return name; }
    public String getTcNo() { return tcNo; }

    public String introduceYourself() {
        String introduction = "My name is " + name + ". I have a cat called " + cat.getName();
        System.out.println(introduction);
        return introduction;
    }
}
```

Cat class:

```
public class Cat {
    private String name;
    public Cat (String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
}
```

Main:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person person = new Person("Person name", "12345");
        Cat cat = new Cat("Cat name");
        person.introduceYourself();
    }
}
```

How can I make the cat object to refer to the person's cat?

Comment: why not give Person a `getCat(Cat cat)` method?

Comment: Create a [getter and setter](https://www.codejava.net/coding/java-getter-and-setter-tutorial-from-basics-to-best-practices) for the Cat object inside the Person class.